# How can I edit a Markdown file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, markdown

I can't figure out how can I edit a Markdown file in Xcode. The file appears to be rendered in a read only mode. Is there any setting that allows me to edit Markdown files in Xcode?

I'm trying to add note to apple's sample project's README.md https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/drawing_with_pencilkit

[image: Screenshot of a Markdown file opened in Xcode]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your .md file is uneditable, you're likely not in Source Code mode. Right click on the file in the Project navigator (the left panel on your screenshot, if it's not visible, press Cmd+1) and select **Open As/Source Code**.

[image: Screenshot of the context menu]

If you want to edit .md files in an Xcode project downloaded from the Apple Developer site, delete these two files in the project folder before opening the project:

```
Configuration/SampleCode.xcconfig
[project name].xcodeproj/.xcodesamplecode.plist
```

Here's how too access the second file:

- Right-click on the .xcodeproj file in Finder and select Show Package Contents.
- If hidden files are not visible in Finder, press <kbd>⌘⇧.</kbd> (Cmd+Shift+period).

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this still didn't solve my problem. I'm trying to add note to apple's sample project's readme. But I still can't edit using the method provided. Is there any setting in this project I'm missing? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/drawing_with_pencilkit

Comment: @LegolasWang I've added some instructions on how to do that with example projects.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer solved my problem perfectly. I heard about .xcodesamplecode.plist forcing markdown into rendered mode. But failed to find it in the past. Thank you for the detailed instructions.

Comment: So if you want to see it rendered, you have to create that `.xcodesamplecode.plist` file, and if you want to edit it, you have to move or delete that file? There is no way to edit and see it rendered without using that file to toggle between the two modes?

Comment: Since everything failed, I had to open it in with an External editor :(  at least that worked

Answer (score 2):

For xcode 12:

Right inspector panel, change **Type** to be: **swift source**

Close editor

Right click file, '**open as source code**' again

Answer (score 2):

As of Xcode 13.2.1 this is still broken. Here's an ugly workaround:

1. Create a file in your `Project.xcodeproj/` directory named `.xcodesamplecode.plist` and copy into it the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array/>
</plist>
```

2. Step 1 will cause Xcode to render `README.md` as markdown in read-only mode.
3. To edit the markdown, close all windows and/or tabs in which `README.md` is visible.
4. Rename `README.md` to anything else with a `.md` suffix, for example `editable.md`.
5. Now open `editable.md` and it will be editable.
6. When finished editing close all `editable.md` windows and rename it back to `README.md`.
7. File a bug report with Apple.