# How can I have a rendered markdown file in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Some times I need the document the important decisions in choosing approach or documenting current issue or bugges of framework or app or even future updates to code or new goals! This all things are just private and just for developer, I was using *.txt file for that then I update it to *.md file. But using *.md file is not all what I wanted, for example for having big title we should use `#` before title, but the sign of `#` is visible when I want read it and it is kind of annoying.  Like this:

[image]

I have to say i am not looking to make documentation for functions or structs or other things. I just want type some text about app itself. How can i remove `#` from *.md file in render mode when I need read it. I know there is an option about playground but I do not want use it. I think a *.md file is good for my use case if I could make it looks nicer, also I have no idea how can I add link or make text bold or add a pic to my *.md file. Again this *.md file is just for me and it is going no where like GitHub it would stay private inside project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I edit a Markdown file in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583811/how-can-i-edit-a-markdown-file-in-xcode)

Answer (score 7):

Place the `.xcodesamplecode.plist` in your `foo.xcworkspace` directory if you have a workspace named foo. If you are just working with a project, place it in your `foo.xcodeproj` dir.

The content should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0"> <array/> </plist>
```

But there are some nuances:
After that, editing .md files will not be very convenient.

To edit the contents of the .md file:

1. Open your .md file
2. Go to right navigation pane and select "Show the File inspector"
3. Change "Type" to the another type. For example: "Objective-C Source"
4. Close your markdown file
5. Select your file from the navigation pane and open as "Quick Look"

To view/render the contents of the .md file:

1. Open your .md file
2. Go to right navigation pane and select "Show the File inspector"
3. Change "Type" to the "Markdown text"
4. Close your markdown file
5. Select your file from the navigation pane and open as "Quick Look"

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSf74.gif)

This is of course not very convenient. Instead, I recommend you install some kind of Markdown Editor

Comment: I cannot follow the part of "Place the .xcodesamplecode.plist in your foo.xcworkspace directory if you have a workspace named foo. If you are just working with a project, place it in your foo.xcodeproj dir." No idea how? can you show with a video or gif?

Comment: foo.xcodeproj or foo.workspace are not files, they are bundles -- that is, directories. Right-click on one of those and choose "Show Package Contents" to reveal the folder's contents. Then place the .xcodesamplecode.plist in that folder. Note: It is a hidden file -- the filename must begin with a period.